# How to loop this object without IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

[image]

i'm simply trying to loop all the [image]

items[x] inside the results object (the function returning this object i own and it returns just a list of string basically). this is coming from a vb.net function that i created for web services purposes. i thought that doing a foreach loop would have been the easier most efficient thing to do but i cant do that because my class does not implement IEnumerable. However i'm wondering if there is yet and easier way to loop this without using iEnumerable.
Your help would be greatly appreciated.
this is what the class looks like being return by my function.

```
Public Class GetErrors 
    Public FWWDIR_ERR_VENDOR As String = String.Empty
    Public FWWDIR_ERR_INVOICE As String = String.Empty
    Public FWWDIR_ERR_ACCOUNT As String = String.Empty
    Public FWWDIR_ERR_FUND As String = String.Empty
    Public FWWDIR_ERR_ORGN As String = String.Empty
    Public FWWDIR_ERR_PROG As String = String.Empty
    Public FWWDIR_ERR_ADDRSS_TYP As String = String.Empty
    Public FWWDIR_ERR_ADDRSS_SEQ As String = String.Empty
    Public FWWDIR_ERR_LOCATION As String = String.Empty
    Public FWWDIR_ERR_ACTIVITY As String = String.Empty
    Public FWWDIR_ROW As String = String.Empty
    Public service_error As String = String.Empty
    Public FWWDIR_ERR_PO As String = String.Empty
    Public FWWDIR_ERR_CHKVEND As String = String.Empty
    Public FWWDIR_ERR_FSYR As String = String.Empty
    Public FWWDIR_ERR_FSPD As String = String.Empty
    Public FWWDIR_ERR_ONTM_VEND As String = String.Empty
    Public FWWDIR_ERR_ONTM_ADRS1 As String = String.Empty
    Public FWWDIR_ERR_ONTM_CITY As String = String.Empty
    Public FWWDIR_ERR_ONTM_STATE As String = String.Empty
    Public FWWDIR_ERR_ONTM_ZIP As String = String.Empty
    Public FWWDIR_ERR_ENCUM_AMT As String = String.Empty
    Public FWWDIR_ERR_ENCUM_VEND As String = String.Empty
    Public FWWDIR_ERR_ITEM_ERROR As String = String.Empty
    Public FWWDIR_POHD As String = String.Empty
End Class
```

short code snipet of that i tried.

```
ServiceApUtils _apUtils = new ServiceApUtils();
var   results = _apUtils.ADP_Processor(l_taxcode.ToArray(), l_amount.ToArray(), l_row.ToArray());
//Response.Write(results[0].)
if (results[0].service_error!="")
{
    Response.Write(results[0].service_error);

}
else if (results.Count > 0)//
{
    for (int x = 0; x < results.Count; x++ ) //typecast x a get error to loop the results
    {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        Table1.Rows.Add(tr);
        foreach (string value in results[x])//fails here with Ienumerable error
        {
           TableCell tc = new TableCell();
           tc.Text = results[x].FWWDIR_ROW + results[x].FWWDIR_ERR_INVOICE + results[x].FWWDIR_ERR_ACCOUNT;
           tr.Cells.Add(tc);// = new TableCell();
        }
    }
}
```

i get an error no matter what i try either iEnumerable error or i simply dont know how to loop inside each array item.

the function using the class as a return is doing this

```
Public Function ADP_Processor(
    ByVal w_taxcode As String(), _
    ByVal w_Amount As String(), _
    ByVal w_row As String()) As List(Of GetErrors)
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what is your question about, but note that `foreach` in C# does not require `IEnumerable` to work - check out last remark in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9yb8xew9.aspx

Comment: according to visual studio 2012 and .net framework 4.0 it does? I cant perform the foreach loop and thats basically the question im looking for another way to do this.

Comment: What is the type of each item in results? Is it an array of strings?

Comment: Aren't they properties/fields of the result[i] object. Based on your screenshot, it doesn't seem to me that they are collection members. They look like fields.

Comment: the type as you can tell from the images is string.

Comment: I have a class getErrors that is basically returning an object with string arrays in them , Imtrying to loop but im not getting anywhere.

Comment: I ask because you enumerate through results[x] as strings and then access results[x].FWWDIR_ROW. If each item in results[x] were strings, then they would not have a property named FWWDIR_ROW.

Comment: @Miguel `foreach` only needs 4 methods: "If the class has the required `GetEnumerator`, `MoveNext`, `Reset`, and `Current` members, it will work with foreach". It is probably not going to help you with enumeration of collection you don't own/write.

Comment: What is the type returned by results[x]? The way its used in the foreach it doesn't look like an array of strings.

Comment: I have updated the post with the related information is basically a list of string

Comment: GetErrors is not a list of strings its a class with a bunch of string fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing your foreach and have:

```
for (int x = 0; x < results.Count; x++ ) //typecast x a get error to loop the results
{
  TableRow tr = new TableRow();
  Table1.Rows.Add(tr);

  GetErrors value = results[x];

  TableCell tc = new TableCell();
  tc.Text = results[x].FWWDIR_ROW + results[x].FWWDIR_ERR_INVOICE + results[x].FWWDIR_ERR_ACCOUNT;
  tr.Cells.Add(tc);// = new TableCell();
}
```

Is appears you are trying to use a class like a method and therefore the fields like an array of strings. Each item in "results" is an instance of the GetErrors class and you cannot use it in a foreach unless you implement IEnumerable and have the GetEnumerator return the values in each of the fields.

Comment: Error 1 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'GetErrors' because 'GetErrors' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator' C:\Users\XXX3\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\testTablesCreation\finutils\Control\ADPControlProcessor.ascx.cs 98 30 testTablesCreation
here is the error

Comment: if you look at my recent edit youll notice that when the calling function returns the class is returning as a list of

Comment: You are not returning a list of strings. You are returning a list of GetErrors instances with each instance containing a number of string fields.

Comment: i get it now. thank you i'm must appreciative for your reponse it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in your loop:

```
 foreach (string value in results[x])//fails here with Ienumerable error
                       {

                           TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                           tc.Text = results[x].FWWDIR_ROW + results[x].FWWDIR_ERR_INVOICE    +                                         results[x].FWWDIR_ERR_ACCOUNT;
                           tr.Cells.Add(tc);// = new TableCell();
                       }
```

you are looping the array of the result set, however you can't do a foreach on the result[x] as foreach requires the results[x] to be an ienumerable. essentially if you were to write:

```
foreach (string value in results){ 
   //logic here 
}
```

then value takes all the values that are stored in one instance of the results set. Now that value is your array of strings you can loop over value with a simple for loop, see below:

```
      ServiceApUtils _apUtils = new ServiceApUtils();
           var   results = _apUtils.ADP_Processor(l_taxcode.ToArray(), l_amount.ToArray(),  l_row.ToArray());
                //Response.Write(results[0].)
             if (results[0].service_error!="")
             {
                 Response.Write(results[0].service_error);

             }//if the procedure has service errors
             else if (results.Count > 0)//
             {
                 foreach (var value in results){
                     TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                     Table1.Rows.Add(tr);
                       for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++{
                         //might have to update this logic as well:
                         TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                         tc.Text = value.FWWDIR_ROW + value.FWWDIR_ERR_INVOICE + value.FWWDIR_ERR_ACCOUNT;
                         tr.Cells.Add(tc);// = new TableCell();
                       }
      }
```